# Live bytes are same as Overall bytes for all rows

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

I have Xcode 3.2.6 and Instruments 2.7 and I am beginner with those applications.

When I run any iPhone project (even simplest navigation controlled app) into Instruments (checking for Memory leak) Live bytes are always same as Overall bytes and they both increase (and sometimes decrease, but not so much as it increased).

It is funny that even Living and Overall are same for all rows.
I really do not understand. I do not have memory leak, I release new UIViewController after pushing into navigation, and I released all NSStrings that I used in my simple test project.

Do I understand something wrong?

Comment: Enable Run Static Analyser in the build settings, then build and run. It will tell you if you do memory management wrong. It is the best thing ever since Stack Overflow.

Comment: thank you, great tool
but what about problem in my Instruments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Leaks template, the Allocations instrument is initially configured to track only active allocations. When you track only active allocations, the live bytes and overall bytes are going to be the same.

To track all memory allocations instead of only the active allocations, click the Info button next to the Allocations instrument and deselect the Only track active allocations checkbox.

[image]